# how to disable llvm-c-test in buiding llvm with mingw32

Tags: c, llvm

I am trying to build llvm-3.4 stable release on mingw32 (www.mingw.org) using cmake and g++4.8.1. I encountered this error:

```
[ 98%] Building C object tools/llvm-c-test/CMakeFiles/llvm-c-test.dir/include-al
l.c.obj
In file included from c:/temp/llvm-3.4/tools/llvm-c-test/include-all.c:33:0:
C:/temp/llvm-3.4/include/llvm-c/lto.h:158:54: error: unknown type name 'off_t'
                                     size_t map_size, off_t offset);
```

After some research, it turns out that this is due to a subdirectory `llvm-c-test` uses non-standard type `off_t`, yet requested itself being compiled using standard C, and that llvm-c-test is not essential.

I tried to disable llvm-c-test by commenting it out in the `tools/CMakeList.txt`. But still I am getting this error.

My question is, how to disable compilation of llvm-c-test or otherwise solve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you, I'm sure there must be a proper way to disable the target using CMake. I've finally abandoned CMake (for MinGW at least) and gone with the makefile configure script instead. Instructions for using this build method are [here](https://github.com/valtron/owl/wiki/Build-LLVM-with-MinGW32-and-MSYS).

Then to disable the llvm-c-test target you can just delete it from the end of the PARALLEL_DIRS variable in *< llvm >/tools/Makefile*:

```
PARALLEL_DIRS := opt llvm-as llvm-dis llc llvm-ar llvm-nm llvm-link \
             lli llvm-extract llvm-mc bugpoint llvm-bcanalyzer llvm-diff \
             macho-dump llvm-objdump llvm-readobj llvm-rtdyld \
             llvm-dwarfdump llvm-cov llvm-size llvm-stress llvm-mcmarkup \
             llvm-profdata llvm-symbolizer obj2yaml yaml2obj llvm-c-test
```

There is [another problem](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2043/) with the MinGW build (from llvm trunk) at the moment, which you may also encounter. The make command line fix seems to work.

Comment: Thanks. This worked as described. Any pointers for building llvm on TDM-GCC 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with CMake. It's a bug in the special [MinGW tool chain](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-setup.exe/download), which Ting used. All other 32-bit MinGW tool chains compile llvm-3.4 successfully with CMake 2.8.12.2, even under 64-bit Windows:

1. TDM-GCC
2. MinGW-Builds
3. Win-Builds
4. MSys2

[MSys2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/files/Base/x86_64/msys2-base-x86_64-20140216.tar.xz/download) can even compile it with the 64-bit tool chain, just update binutils with pacman and set "CXXFLAGS=-Wa,-mbig-obj". (Unfortunately no updates available for the other tool chains at the time writing.)

By the way: Even if you set "CXXFLAGS=-D_GLIBCXX_HAVE_FENV_H" with llvm-3.0 through llvm-3.2 , the old MinGW tool chain will run into errors (the other tool chains will run into other errors):

```
llvm-3.0\llvm\tools\clang\lib\Basic\FileManager.cpp:290:66: error: no matching function for call to 'clang::FileManager::getStatValue(const char*&, _stat64i32&, int)'
llvm-3.0\llvm\tools\clang\lib\Basic\FileManager.cpp:358:61: error: no matching function for call to 'clang::FileManager::getStatValue(const char*&, _stat64i32&, int*)'
llvm-3.0\llvm\tools\clang\lib\Basic\FileManager.cpp:429:61: error: no matching function for call to 'clang::FileManager::getStatValue(const char*&, _stat64i32&, int*)'
llvm-3.0\llvm\tools\clang\lib\Basic\FileManager.cpp:539:6: error: prototype for 'bool clang::FileManager::getStatValue(const char*, _stat64i32&, int*)' does not match any in class 'clang::FileManager'
llvm-3.0\llvm\tools\clang\lib\Basic\FileManager.cpp:554:6: error: prototype for 'bool clang::FileManager::getNoncachedStatValue(llvm::StringRef, _stat64i32&)' does not match any in class 'clang::FileManager'
llvm-3.1\llvm\tools\clang\lib\Basic\FileManager.cpp:295:66: error: no matching function for call to 'clang::FileManager::getStatValue(const char*&, _stat64i32&, int)'
llvm-3.1\llvm\tools\clang\lib\Basic\FileManager.cpp:363:61: error: no matching function for call to 'clang::FileManager::getStatValue(const char*&, _stat64i32&, int*)'
llvm-3.1\llvm\tools\clang\lib\Basic\FileManager.cpp:434:61: error: no matching function for call to 'clang::FileManager::getStatValue(const char*&, _stat64i32&, int*)'
llvm-3.1\llvm\tools\clang\lib\Basic\FileManager.cpp:544:6: error: prototype for 'bool clang::FileManager::getStatValue(const char*, _stat64i32&, int*)' does not match any in class 'clang::FileManager'
llvm-3.1\llvm\tools\clang\lib\Basic\FileManager.cpp:559:6: error: prototype for 'bool clang::FileManager::getNoncachedStatValue(llvm::StringRef, _stat64i32&)' does not match any in class 'clang::FileManager'
llvm-3.2\llvm\projects\compiler-rt\lib\enable_execute_stack.c:13:22: fatal error: sys/mman.h: No such file or directory
```

The last error with llvm-3.2 is indeed common for all MinGW tool chains as the following error with llvm-3.3:

```
mingw32-make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'lib/Target/AArch64/AArch64GenSubtargetInfo.inc', needed by 'lib/Target/AArch64/Utils/CMakeFiles/LLVMAArch64Utils.dir/AArch64BaseInfo.cpp.obj'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Could you give specific steps needed for building llvm under TDM-GCC 64? I tried it earlier and run into problems with caml bindings, which prevents llvm from functioning http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478383 . Thanks

Comment: MSys2 is the only 64-bit tool chain I know, which can compile llvm-3.4. TDM-GCC-64 will run into the following error: "c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as.exe: CMakeFiles\clangDynamicASTMatchers.dir\Registry.cpp.obj: too many sections (39644)". Unfortunately there is no update of binutils available for TDM-GCC.